# Publishing dotNet 6 SPA application on IIS server returns error: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am trying to publish my react redux dotnet 6 SPA app on an IIS server, but I get an error:

Error message:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually.
```

Which I think it explains the problem but I am cannot resolve it. I tried several configs, but still I get the same error.

Here I am including my `Program.cs` and `MyDemoProject.csproj` file:

Program.cs

```cs
var spaSrcPath = "Web";
var corsPolicyName = "AllowAll";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add CORS
builder.Services.AddCorsConfig(corsPolicyName);

// Register Controllers
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Add Brotli/Gzip response compression (prod only)
builder.Services.AddResponseCompressionConfig(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddMvc(opt => opt.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);

// In production, the Vue files will be served from this directory
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(opt => opt.RootPath = $"{spaSrcPath}/dist");

// Register the Swagger services (using OpenApi 3.0)
builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument(settings =>
{
  settings.Version = "v1";
  settings.Title = "My Demo Project API";
  settings.Description = "Documentation of the api ....";
});


var app = builder.Build();

// If development, enable Hot Module Replacement
// If production, enable Brotli/Gzip response compression & strict transport security headers
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
  app.UseResponseCompression();
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  app.UseHsts();
}

// Global exception handling
app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
{
  builder.Run(async context =>
  {
    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
    var exDetails = new ExceptionDetails((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error?.Error.Message ?? "");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = exDetails.StatusCode;
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", exDetails.Message);
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Application-Error");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(exDetails.ToString());
  });
});

app.UseCors(corsPolicyName);

app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { RequestPath = $"/{spaSrcPath}/build" });
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

// Map controllers
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
  spa.Options.SourcePath = spaSrcPath;
  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
});

app.Run();
```

MyDemoProject.csproj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>Web\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <AssemblyName>MyDemoProject</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>MyDemoProject</RootNamespace>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>False</EnableNETAnalyzers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.6.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.15.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.MSBuild" Version="13.15.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**;$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder);@(Content)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Reference)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)References" />
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Net60) run /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration) /runtime:Net60" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutDir)References" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install --force" />
    <!-- Updated to react 18.0, should not interfere with the build process -->
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install --force" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And I am using command below to build and publish the app:

```
dotnet publish --arch x64
```

And this is my folder structure, I am including the folders and files that I think are relevant to my problem:

```
MyDemoProject
  Backend
    Base
      Program.cs
    Models
    Services
  Web
    build
    node_modules
    public
      index.html
    src
      App.tsx
      index.tsx
    appsettings.json
  MyDemoProject.csproj
  web.config
  Mobile
    ...
    ...
    ...
MyProject.sln
```

Comment: Check you spa path, $"{spaSrcPath}/dist" conformity to folder structure.

Comment: Or try add to web.config <system.webServer>
   ...
      <defaultDocument enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>

Comment: @MihalBy  added the line on the second comment and now it returns 403 error, but can you tell me what should I check at the spa path?

Comment: Exists  "index.html" and "static" folder in you web\build?  In you code SPA expected in .../dist folder. `// In production, the Vue files will be served from this directory
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(opt => opt.RootPath = $"{spaSrcPath}/dist");`Change "dist" to "build" or build SPA to new "dist" folder.